# Do C2DM and/or APNS travel over the "control channel" used by SMS?

Tags: sms, apple-push-notifications, android-c2dm

Curious how messages sent via C2DM for Android and APNS for iOS actually make it to a device. Do they travel over the "control channel", [described here](http://communication.howstuffworks.com/sms.htm), that is also used by carriers for SMS? Have Apple/Google worked with carriers to build their own equivalent "control channel"? Or do these devices simply wake up and poll a server every X seconds in a way that is carrier/network independent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think devices maintain persistent socket connection for receiving notifications. Try by disconnecting data connection and you wont receive push notification. (iPhone uses port 5223 on WiFi for push notifications)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this is also true of devices with 3G connectivity? Seems like having a socket connection open 100% of the time would kill your iPhone battery, hence the value of the control channel.